# Change File name by it's 2nd line content

Tags: rename

I have a `Config.cfg` file and I want to rename it by putting the value of 2nd line in the name of the file.

Example:

```
$ more Config.cfg 
!
!  Configuration last changed by user '%LICM%' at Tue Jul  4 15:17:04 2017
!
!
!
global synchronization option 2
```

Expected Result :

```
Config Jul  4 15:17:04 2017.cfg
```

Comment: Is the format of the second line always exactly the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

- with sed, extract the 2nd line
- with awk, extract the trailing fields and print the surrounding static text
- if successful, rename the file with that generated value

Code:

```
val=$(sed -n 2p Config.cfg | 
      awk '{print "Config " $(NF-3) " " $(NF-2) " " $(NF-1) " " $NF ".cfg"}')
[[ -n "$val" ]] && mv Config.cfg "$val"
```

Comment: Why not use `NR==2` in `awk` and skip the `sed`?

Comment: Certainly could! I wasn't sure I was going to use awk, so I started with sed to get line #2 and went from there.

Comment: Fair enough!  of course, this doesn't exactly produce the filename in the expected output either since a single digit day number will end up with 2 spaces between it and the month there and only 1 with yours

Comment: `printf "Config %s %-2i %02i:%02i:%02i %04i.cfg", $(NF-3), $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF;`.   better yet, do it in `perl` which has a built-in `rename()` function.

Comment: OTOH. deliberately making filenames with spaces - lots of spaces - in them on unix is just......wrong.  use `-` or `_` or `.`.    and, more importantly, @Nydenn should use [YYYY-MM-DD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  It's the only date format that's competely unambiguous and sorts correctly.

Comment: @Jeff +`NR==2` as Eric pointed out, also you could use `-F"at"` and only print `$NF` was enough

Answer (score 0):

Only with `sed` you extract your filename:

```
mv file "$(sed -n '/Configuration/s/.*at [^ ]*/Config/p' file)"
```